# Unable to upload/save/read csv files in Flask

Tags: python, pandas, csv, flask, xgboost

So, I'm currently deploying two XGBoost models on a Flask webserver, and one of the ways to input data is by uploading a csv file.

I then need to save this csv file on the server (with a 8-digit hexcode for it's name), then pass it's filepath to a function that'll read the csv file into a pandas dataframe and pass it to one of the two models depending on the column names (or return an error instead). The model predictions will then be added to the csv file as an extra column, and the csv file will be saved again (this time with a "_out" suffix).

My exact subset of flask code to achieve all this is as follows:

```
def predict(path):
  data = pd.read_csv(path)
  if data.columns.values.tolist() == ['Leukocytes', 'Platelets', 'Eosinophils', 'Monocytes']:
    data['Prediction'] = model4.predict(data)
    out = 1
    pathout = os.path.join('uploads', path, '_out.csv'.format(n)
    data.to_csv(pathout)
  elif data.columns.values.tolist() == ['Hematocrit', 'Hemoglobin', 'Platelets', 'MPV', 'Erythrocytes', 'Lymphocytes', 'MCHC', 'Leukocytes', 'Basophils', 'MCH', 'Eosinophils', 'MCV', 'Monocytes', 'RDW']:
    data['Prediction'] = model14.predict(data)
    out = 2
    pathout = os.path.join('uploads', path, '_out.csv'.format(n)
    data.to_csv(pathout)
  else:
    out = 3
    pathout = os.path.join('uploads', path, '_out.csv'.format(n)
    data.to_csv(pathout)
  return out, pathout

@app.route("/csvIn", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def csvInput():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    csv = request.files['file']
    if not os.path.isdir('uploads'):
      os.mkdir('uploads')
    path = os.path.join('uploads', secrets.token_hex(8))
    csv.save(path)
    out, pathout = predict(path)
    return redirect(url_for('csvOut', out = out, pathout = pathout))
  return render_template("csv.html")

@app.route("/csvOut", methods=['POST'])
def csvOut():
  pathout = request.args.get("pathout")
  out = request.args.get("out")
  if out == 1:
    result = "Please find the predicted output in the column titled 'Prediction' in the file attached below"
  elif out == 2:
    result = "Please find the predicted output in the column titled 'Prediction' in the file attached below"
  else:
    result = "The uploaded csv file does not match the provided template. Please recheck the CSV file below and upload again. \n If the problem persists, please contact the admin teams for further clarification."
  return render_template("out.html", pathout = pathout, result = result)
```

The html file out.html is pretty basic:

```
<head>
  <title>Batch Prediction</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <h2><b> Result: {{ result }} </b></h2><br>
    <p>If the file format is correct, the model predictions have been appended to the dataset in the form of a feature titled "Prediction".</p><br>
    <a href = "{{ pathout }}" download><button>Download File</button></a><br>
    <a href="/home"><button class="btnbl">Return Home</button></a>
  </div>
</body>
```

So after running the flask app, it can't seem to save the uploaded csv file to the specified location, and thus the out.html always returns an error. I do not understand where I am going wrong with this. Please help.

Obligatory disclaimer: I am a biologist by education, and my coding knowledge is quite limited.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you print the **path** and**pathout** variable for testing. The **path** variable that you reading should contain the folder path followed by csv file extention and **pathout** should contain the proper folder path. Please post the error that what you getting.

Comment: @BerlinBenilo There is none. When I try uploading a file, it isn't saved in the **uploads** folder for some reason. Doing so takes me to the **/csvOut** page, but it always returns an error, i.e., **out = 3** in **predict()**. I think the problem lies in saving the uploaded file..

Comment: @BerlinBenilo The output for both is **None**